# What is a typical value for the gain of a smartphone's Bluetooth (or Wi-Fi) antenna?

Tags: signal, antenna, signal-processing, gain

I can't find specific values for transmitter and receiver gain anywhere. Very often the Bluetooth module is together with the Wi-Fi module, so a Wi-Fi antenna gain value will help me as well.
I need to find the value in order to use it in some path loss formulas, but my smartphone's spec does not specify the value, so it would be useful to know more or less what a typical value would be for a smartphone.

Comment: If its possible, find the values experimentally. This question is too broad, there are thousands of bluetooth module\antenna combos and the question cannot be answered because I don't think anyone wants to compile a list of path loss for every module that exists. Please read this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago, I myself had to look that up and the answer is pretty complex.

One of the big issues is that in path-loss formulas, it is usually taken for granted that the antennas are pointing to each-other with their highest gain directions and therefore only highest gain is used for calculations.

In reality, you have a 3D figure showing you the gain of the physical antenna. That figure will have a shape of its own. While, as Electrical Architect mentioned in his answer, it would be very good if you didn't have to keep track of your direction when using portable devices, in reality the gain figures can be very non-spherical and they are frequency-dependent as well.

That is why, in a datasheet for an antenna, you will be able to find several gain values such as peak maximum gain and band-edge maximum gain. Those values are not particularly interesting, because they're the best case. You, as the user, do not know which antenna is in your device or how it is positioned, even if you manage to find the datasheet.

If you dig a bit more through the datasheets, you'll be able to find average gain (sometimes even for a frequency!), or mean effective gain or similar value. This is a more meaningful value, since it can give you a number that does not depend on the orientation as much.

Finally, you also might also find a minimum gain value somewhere in a table on on a graph. If you want to make the absolute worst case calculation for your system, you can use this, but be warned: Sometimes the difference between the maximum and minimum value can be over 20 dB!

OK, so enough theory,you don't have the datasheets, so let me give you some values: I'd say that you can use around -1.1 dB to -2 dB as a gain figure for 2.4 GHz  to 2.5 GHz chip antennas that can be currently easily found. Keywords for Google that produce datasheets are: `WiFi SMD antennas`

Here are some datahseets that I read:
http://www.mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/documents/w3008.pdf
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Acc-Antanova-Chip-Ant-DS.pdf  http://www.pulseelectronics.com/download/2987/w3108pdf/pdf

Answer (score 1):

Consider that the gain of an antenna is a function of the direction of the space around it.

That said, you usually don't want to point you smartphone or tablet in the direction of an access point, but you'd rather use it moving around without caring about your position relative to the transmitter.

This means you need an antenna that radiates roughly the same amount of power in every (spherical) direction.

So a well designed wireless system (Bluetooth or WiFi) has to be based on an antenna with a gain *around* 0 dBi (i.e. a gain around 1, if you use linear units).

Comment: I don't know, but I imagine -3dBi would  be a hard target to meet in a small package. Too many lossy components about. If you'd said -10 dBi, that would be as convincing...

Comment: @Sean Houlihane Do you have any sources for that? To me, this looks a bit too pessimistic.

Comment: Agreed, -10 might be OK for an electrically small antenna. Should be somewhere better than that.

Comment: Actually, when you consider the added lossy antenna element of the electrically HUGE **hand** that's nearly always positioned <1/4 wave from the driven element of the antenna, I think I'd consider -20dB a reasonable guess. At 2.4GHz ISM-band (bluetooth & 802.11b/g wifi, iirc), 1/4 wavelength is a little over an inch (3 cm), so anything within 1-2 inches of the antenna should be considered pretty much as part of the antenna itself (like a director or reflector element) when running simulations to calculate radiation patterns (gain).